# Vector container and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, unique-ptr

I have searched for hours for a solution and tried different methods to address my compilation errors related to `unique_ptr` and no copy/no assign.  I even wrote a hidden copy and assign to prevent vector from calling it to no avail.

Here is the code causing the compilation errors:

```
class World{
    World(const World&) {}
    World& operator=(const World&) {return *this; }

    std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Organism>>> cell_grid;
public:
    World() {
        cell_grid = std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Organism>>> (20, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Organism>> (20, nullptr));
    }
    ~World() {}
};
```

Compilation errors are related to the private member access issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the use of this `vector` constructor:

```
vector(size_type n, const T& value);
```

This constructor creates a `vector` of length `n` and each of the `n` elements has a **copy** of `value`.  Since `unique_ptr` can not be copied (and neither can a `vector<unique_ptr>`), one can not use this constructor.  Instead do this:

```
World()
    : cell_grid(20)
{
    for (auto& row : cell_grid)
        row.resize(20);
}
```

The first line calls the default constructor of `vector<unique_ptr>`, creating 20 size 0 `vector<unique_ptr>`s.

The loop then resizes each of those `vector<unique_ptr>`s to have size == 20, with each element being a default constructed `unique_ptr` (which will have the value `nullptr`).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.  Very clear and concise.  I will refer to cppreference.com in the future but I wanted an answer from this community as I thought I had performed a thorough search.  Thank you again for taking the time to answer my question.